# State of WKWebView on Cordova iOS 9?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

iOS 8 introduced WKWebView, a modernised web view for iOS with more features, particularly notably JIT compilation for Javascript code which significantly improves performance.

However WKWebView on iOS 8 had some bugs which prevented Cordova using it by default. AFAIK there are plugins that can use it, but they all say "beta", "incomplete" etc. Also as far as I'm aware iOS 9 fixes the bugs that stopped Cordova defaulting to WKWebView in iOS 8.

So what is the state of WKWebView in Cordova on iOS 9? I can't seem to find any information about this. Does Cordova default to WKWebView on iOS 9? If not why not, and can it be officially enabled another way?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

New edit: **June 2019**

Apple has not removed `UIWebView` in iOS 13 beta, so looks like it can be used at least for another year.

Ionic WebView plugin, starting in version 3.0.0 no longer uses a web server, but the `WKURLSchemeHandler` instead, that required to drop support for iOS 10 and older.

Still backport most fixes to 2.x branch that still have the web server for those that want to support iOS 10.

WKWebView was not integrated into cordova-ios 5.0.0, a plugin is still required to use it. Should be there for 6.0.0 version.

And now there is Ionic **Capacitor** available, an Apache Cordova alternative that was built with the `WKWebView` since the beginning. It has its own set of plugins, but it's also compatible with most Cordova plugins. 
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/

Old edit: **August 2018**

Apple has deprecated `UIWebView` in iOS 12 and will probably remove it in iOS 13.

Apache Cordova [has announced](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2018/08/01/future-cordova-ios-webview.html) that it will integrate the `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` into `cordova-ios` in next major release (5.x.x), but `UIWebView` will still work and be the default one. Also, you'll be able to switch between them in runtime to easily test your app.
In a future release it will remove the whole `UIWebView` code and the `WKWebView` will be the only option.

But `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` still have a lot of issues. I still recommend using [cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) as using `GCDWebServer` solves most of the `WKWebView` issues.

New edit: **November 2017**

Ionic team has launched a [new WKWebView plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) that is no longer a fork of the Cordova one and uses `GCDWebServer` internally and overcomes most of the Cordova plugin known issues.

New edit: **24 August 2016**

Updated just to add a fork of the apache's `WKWebView` plugin created by the ionic framework team that adds some enhancements to the plugin.

https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

The enhancements will probably land on the core plugin soon, but you can take a look and test the ionic fork now.

New edit: **9 December 2015**

cordova ios 4.0.0 [has been released](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/12/08/cordova-ios-4.0.0.html) 
and [the version 1.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/12/08/wkwebview-engine-plugin-release.html) of `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`

To try it:

```
cordova create wkwvtest my.project.id wkwvtest
cd wkwvtest
cordova platform add ios@4
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

As I already told, cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine only supports iOS 9, on iOS 8 it will use UIWebView and has some [know issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10146?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20labels%20%3D%20wkwebview-known-issues)

If you want to support iOS 8 too, you can use the [wkwebview-engine-localhost](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost) (experimental) or [cordova-plugin-wkwebview](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView) from Telerik, both of them use a local web server

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost

OLD MESSAGE:

You can use WKWebView with cordova using the WKWebView plugins available.

The problem you mention is that WKWebView can't load local files, so the plugins use a local web server to workaround the problem.

There are some of them like this one from telerik https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView (with the web server built in) or the official from cordova team https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost (with the web server as dependency plugin)

As the bug you mention is fixed on iOS 9, the current cordova plugin (compatible with iOS 8 and iOS 9, using the web server) has been renamed to wkwebview-engine-localhost, and the current name cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine will be used for a new plugin that will support iOS 9 only and won't use the web server

You can see the issues to track the progress here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9566

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9567

EDIT: I bring news https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/apache-cordova-ios-4-0-0-and-wkwebview-support/

> WKWebView support
>
> The cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin will be iOS 9 only and it
>   will be a core plugin. The development of this updated plugin is still
>   in progress. Apple has fixed the bug where we couldn’t load documents
>   from file:// urls, and it is iOS 9 only. On non-iOS 9 devices,
>   cordova-ios will fallback to using the UIWebView.
>
> The old version of this plugin used a local webserver to load your
>   main document. This older plugin can be used where you want to use
>   WKWebView in both iOS 8 and iOS 9 deployments, but the plugin will
>   remain as a cordova-labs experiment. This plugin has some re-factoring
>   work to be done.

Comment: I see that both jira tickets you mentioned are resolved.  Are the fixes released?

Comment: Not yet, cordova 4.0 is ready and wkwebview plugin too, but they are on release vote proccess, I'll update as soon as they are published.

Comment: Built with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine. How to check if cordova really using WKWebkit? What userAgen string look like?

Comment: WKWebView has indexedDB support, so you can do this: ```if (window.indexedDB) {
    //WKWebView
  }```

Comment: UIWebView also added indexedDB, so best way of checking if WKWebView is `if (window.webkit) {//WKWebView}`

Comment: This is stil the most helpful resource on the net for WKWebView pain. Thank you!

Comment: JUST VIMP COMMENT: I(my team) had uploaded app with UIWebView on AppStore.I got warning, next time it will be rejected. forced me to use wkwebview. so better not use depecreated stuff anymore

Comment: @minigeek, it's just a warning for now, it's unclear when they will start rejecting apps

Comment: They said. ITMS-90809 Deprecated API Usage: Apple will stop accepting apps that use UIWebView. Q is: is this just inAppBrowser related or entire Cordova? Ifcordova.. won't there be big problem for all apps out there based on Cordova? @jcesarmobile

Comment: @minigeek they will stop at some point in the future. They have not provided a date yet. It’s both Cordova and InAppBrowser related. Both of them have pull requests removing UIWebView, but not merged.

Comment: @jcesarmobile thank you so much for clarification. can you please provide me those pull req link. Atleast I can merge on my local, it won't stop me doing publishing. Customer is scared of this warning. Just need to test it on local. Will it be feasible?