# Can I use indexedDB in a cordova iOS application?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile-safari, indexeddb, wkwebview

I'm getting an `InvalidAccessError` when I try to open a Indexed Database in my cordova iOS application.

Platform:

- cordova: 5.4.1
- cordova-ios: 4.0.1
- iOS 9.2 (simulator and real device)

I already added the [Plugin to use the WKWebview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) which made the the indexedDB object at least defined, but the error is thrown. The code works in chrome, safari and mobile safari if I run it via cordova's own web server.

config.xml looks like this

```
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

and I try to open the indexedDB with this:

```
openDb: function() {
    var openRequest = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        console.log('upgrade needed');
        console.log(event);
        myIndexDb = event.target.result;
        var options = {
            autoIncrement: true,
            keyPath: 'key'
        };
        var objectStore = myIndexDb.createObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, options);
    };
    openRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log('indexDB open Error!');
    };
    openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log('open success');
        myIndexDb = this.result;
    };
    openRequest.onblocked = function(event) {
        console.log('request is blocked');
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it works with the Telerik Plugin https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView (and cordova-ios 3.9.2)

Comment: cordova-ios 4.9.2 doesn't exists. There are other alternatives to telerik plugin is you use cordova-ios 4.0.0 or greater http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405798/state-of-wkwebview-on-cordova-ios-9/32452158#32452158

Comment: That was a typo - I meant cordova-ios 3.9.2 - And with the linked `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` indexedDB does not work

Comment: I found using PhoneGap Build I was only able to use the CDWKWebViewEngine plugin if I added it as a plugin to my config.xml - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573145/cordova-wkwebview-plugin-with-phonegap-build-6-0-0

However, as yet I haven't been able to successfully call window.indexedDB.open() from within my app even though window.indexedDB exists.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Looks like `IndexedDB` problems were fixed on iOS 10, and also added it to `UIWebView`.

OLD ANSWER:
The way to workaround the problem with `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` and IndexedDB is to use a local webserver.

You can use the `wkwebview-engine-localhost` plugin to workaround the bug adding the local webserver. To install the plugin use

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost
```

Comment: Be aware that you'll need to assign yourself a fixed tcp port number for the embedded web server or else you'll get a new database every time the application starts and the embedded server selects a new, random, tcp port.