# Cordova WKWebView Plugin with PhoneGap Build Version 6.0.0

Tags: phonegap-build, wkwebview

From the blog post about PhoneGap 6.0.0 being available on Build my understanding is that we can now use the Cordova WKWebView engine with apps build with PhoneGap Build. See:

http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/09/phonegap_6_now_on_build/
https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/apache-cordova-ios-4-0-0-and-wkwebview-support/
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

I've updated my config version to include the following but am still getting the default UIWebView:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" />

<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Has anyone been able to get this working that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this post I found part of my solution http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/does-phonegap-build-support-wkwebview-with-the-new-cli-6-0 - I was missing the following line in my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine"/>
```

However, I also found that I needed to turn off Hydration to get the app past the "initialising" screen.

Comment: This worked for you?  I have the same setup as you, but I can't get it to work.  I'm still getting the errors trying to load my static files off file:// URLs.    I've been trying to get this to work for several hours now, but can't.

Comment: gabaum10 - I've noticed in the README.md for the CDWKWebViewEngine plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) it mentions that you need to enable CORS on your server if you're using XHR. Is this what you're trying to do and does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I finally got it working to serve the local files correctly. However, I still couldn't figure out how to trigger API requests. Those are all failing with various errors. I have CORS implemented, although I suspect my understanding of this is what is causing the errors. I eventually gave up for now and will revisit it later when hopefully the views mature a bit. They still feel a bit cobbled together at the moment.

Comment: I'm still getting the ios warning about deprecating UIWebView so I think it's ignoring the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine. Can anybody help?