# Cordova WKWebView Plugin with PhoneGap not resolving file:// urls - what are the options?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a cordova app I'm building through [Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com) pointing to cordova cli-6.0.0.  I've tried to implement the new cordova [WKWebview plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) but have had zero success.

I am finding conflicting info about this all over the web and can't figure out what the expected behavior is for this WKWebview plugin.  The official docs say that loading resources off the file:// protocol isn't yet supported due to an Apple design decision.  The problem is I'm loading all my static files through requirejs over the file:// protocol.  I suspect it's the fact I'm using requirejs that is breaking this.

I've tried to use the [Experimental Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost) with the local webserver but could not get it to work properly.  If anyone had a good example on how to do that, maybe that's the way to go.

I've also tried to use the [Telerik](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView) plugin, but I can't even get that to build in PhoneGap Build.

Has anyone been able to get WKWebviews to work using phonegap build using cli-6.0.0, specifically when they are loading resources dynamically as the app runs?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Apparently [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573145/cordova-wkwebview-plugin-with-phonegap-build-version-6-0-0) got it working, but he provided very little information aside from what exists in the docs.

Comment: Did you have any luck on figuring it out?